# Agregar clase active y cambiar el color del elemento seleccionado de un menu

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap

```js
$(function() {
  
  // elementos de la lista
  var menues = $(".nav li"); 

  // manejador de click sobre todos los elementos
  menues.click(function() {
     // eliminamos active de todos los elementos
     menues.removeClass("active");
     // activamos el elemento clicado.
     $(this).addClass("active").css('background-color', 'red');
  });

});
```

Comment: ¿Cual es la pregunta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
 $(function() {
    $(".nav > li").click(function() {
    //Busca todos los elementos del nav que tengan la clase active y los elimina
  $(this).closest('.nav').find('li').removeClass('active');
  //Al elemento seleccionado agrega la clase active
          $(this).addClass('active');
      });
});
```

```css
.active{
      background-color: red;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="nav">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</nav>
```